# How do I get gsl to work in Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

I hope I can ask this question here. I have downloaded Asymptote from windows-binaries and want to run an asy-program that contains the row (it has worked a long time ago)

import gsl;

But that seems not to be included in the distribution. The manual says something about If asymptote is compiled with... you have access to the gsl-library.

Obviously the version I downloaded from the webpage is not compiled with gsl. How do I find a version that is, och how do I add it to the version I have?

-anders

Comment: Could you show a code? and also test on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

Comment: What code? I fails on import gsl;